# What expression is it?

Tags: meaning, expressions

While watching another part of BGT, after a team performance a judge said something like:
**"I'm almost at lost of the words"**. I've tried to listen many times, but still can't understand clearly.

I believe something is wrong, as I can't find any similar phrases. The main idea should be: "It was so good that I can't speak now".

Would you help me to identify the original phrase?

Comment: No doubt it was **I'm almost at a loss for words** https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+a+loss+for+words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is "(to be) at a loss for words".
[https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20a%20loss%20for%20words#:~:text=chiefly%20US,at%20a%20loss%20for%20words](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20a%20loss%20for%20words#:%7E:text=chiefly%20US,at%20a%20loss%20for%20words).